# First time building Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first time working with js and building a chrome extension. What I want to achieve is; Chrome extension will ask a user to input a number (minute). Lets suppose user enters 5 as an input. When clicks to start button, extension will click the desired button on the webpage in everry 5 minutes. I did my best to create the basic structure and I got some help from AI. But it is now working. I need help guys

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "AutoClicker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["content.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
let clickingInterval;
let clickDuration = 5; // Default duration in minutes

function clickTargetButton() {
  const button = document.evaluate(
    '/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/button[2]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
    null
  ).singleNodeValue;

  if (button) {
    button.click();
    console.log('Button clicked!');
  } else {
    console.log('Button not found or XPath incorrect.');
  }
}

function startClicking(duration) {
  clickDuration = duration;
  clickTargetButton(); // Click the button immediately when starting
  clickingInterval = setInterval(clickTargetButton, clickDuration * 60 * 1000); // Click the button based on user input
}

function stopClicking() {
  clearInterval(clickingInterval);
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === 'startClicking') {
    const duration = parseInt(message.duration);
    if (!isNaN(duration)) {
      startClicking(duration);
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid duration provided.');
    }
  } else if (message.action === 'stopClicking') {
    stopClicking();
  }
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Auto Clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Auto Clicker</h1>
  <label for="interval">Set Interval (in minutes): </label>
  <input type="number" id="interval" min="1" value="5">
  <br><br>
  <button id="startButton">Start</button>
  <button id="stopButton">Stop</button>

  <script src="popup.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const duration = document.getElementById('interval').value;
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'startClicking', duration: duration });
  });
});

document.getElementById('stopButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'stopClicking' });
  });
});
```

I did my best to create the basic structure and I got some help from AI. But it is now working. I need help guys

Comment: Assuming you meant "not working", you need to explain what you mean by it.  What is not working?  How is it not working?  Is it not counting down?  Is it not clicking? Is it clicking something else?  You need to clarify these points.

Comment: 1) Add `defer` to popup.js script tag or move the tag to the end of html. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. 2) You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.

Comment: When I say not working, I mean it is not clicking to the button on the webpage. And nothing shows up on the console when I tried to test it.

Comment: I have added the defer and tried your suggestion. Still no progress. I am lost @wOxxOm Its still not pressing to the button on the webpage

Comment: You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.